# globalAlpha not working with globalCompositeOperation on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas

I am trying to render two rectangles one on the top of other inside canvas element with **globalCompositeOperation set to 'source-out'** and **globalAlpha set to 0.2**. However globalAlpha is not working on **Safari** and the outer rectangle in getting rendered with opacity 1.

Below is the code.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = el.getContext('2d');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(200,200,400,400);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0,0,800,800);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top : 50px;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.canvas-container .canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      This is canvas container
      <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely reproduce the bug, and being a bug, the only true solution is to [report it](https://bugs.webkit.org/) in the hope it gets fixed.

Now, there are a lot of workarounds available.

The first one is to use a semi-transparent `fillStyle` rather than `globalAlpha`:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100,100,200,200);
ctx.fill();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0,400,400);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

But this may not be really practical, for instance if you have complex gradients or even patterns as `fillStyle`.

A second workaround is to use the `fillRect()` method, which **is not** affected by the bug.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100,100,200,200);
ctx.fill();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;

ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

But this will obviously only work for rectangles, and not for any other shapes.

So a third workaround, which is probably the best one, consists in drawing the other way: first draw the semi-transparent contour, then the hole:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');

// first the contour
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0,400,400);
ctx.fill();

// now the hole
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100,100,200,200);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

But if for some reasons you can't even do that, then a last resort workaround is to use a second canvas on which you'll draw your shape and do the compositing through `drawImage()`, which isn't affected either by this bug:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = el.getContext('2d');
const copy_ctx= el.cloneNode().getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100,100,200,200);
ctx.fill();

copy_ctx.beginPath();
copy_ctx.rect(0,0,400,400);
copy_ctx.fill();

// we can set the alpha either here or while drawing
// on copy_ctx, it doesn't change much, both work
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
ctx.drawImage(copy_ctx.canvas,0,0);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```